# Text according to Excel document

Tags: vegas-pro

A friend and I recently launched a model rocket. We had installed an altitudemeter that exports all it's data for each quarter second into an Excel document. I want to take the data of the time and height of this document (about 1000 time steps) and use it to have a live altimeter in the top of the screen on the video using Vegas Pro 13. I basically want it to count the height live with the video. Does anyone know if this is possible in Sony Vegas?
The best thing for me would be that it follows a graph so that the text doesn't change every quarter second, but every frame. If this can be done, it would be easier, because then I don't have to use every single step of time from Excel, but every 10 steps or so. It will still be accurate and smooth, though less of an annoying job.

Comment: You might want to look into using telemetry software, [Dashware](http://www.dashware.net/) for example is free.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this to be done automatically. But f course you could create 1000 text overlays, each one showing a particular altitude, and place the correct overlay at the correct point in the timeline for the correct duration (1/4 second). That would be a terribly tedious job!

Comment: Please don't post an answer if you already know that that's not the solution that anyone is looking for.

Comment: I don't know you, so I didn't know if you are a person who minds tedious jobs. Some people don't. You'd just asked whether Sony Vegas _could_ do it, and this will work. Again, the only confusion was that I don't know _you_ so I didn't know how much experience you have with editing. Some newcomers honestly don't know that they can add text over their videos on the frames they want!

Comment: Haha, okay I understand. Sorry. I have done lots of tedious jobs in the past, though I'm not even sure if I Sony Vegas is going to keep up with little over a thousand little text tracks. I'm running an AMD FX 8350 CPU, which isn't all that stable with video editing.

Comment: It sounds like a really cool project though! I hope someone else has an automated solution for you. Maybe FFMPEG can accomplish what you want? I've never used it, but I've seen a lot of questions and answers about it in this community. FFMPEG has command-line features (I think) that can handle some bulk / repetitive tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is with Vegas scripting. I have not used it myself but it should be able to accomplish what you're looking for.

https://www.vegascreativesoftware.com/us/downloads/#c24726

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel, presumably you have PowerPoint? If so, there may be a way to get what you’re looking for that way. The basic idea would be something like this:

1. Construct a chart using the Excel data;
2. Put that into PowerPoint as a single slide;
3. Animate the slide, suppressing the visual items you do not want to appear;
4. Capture the actual running of that animation with something like Screenflow;
5. Pull the resulting clip into Vegas and stretch it to cover the required time of the rocket flight
6. Lie down in a dark room to recover from the effort

The trick is to choose the most appropriate chart to begin with, with the appropriate chart options, and to then suppress the undesired elements in PP. Done right, you could get anything from as complex as the actual chart series lines, all the way down to nothing but the simple numbers you talk about. I’d do as much as possible of the heavy lifting *in* Excel, and even prior to creating the chart. Consider things like splitting the data points into series that then all use the same x axis values. That’s the kind of thing that would let you get the consecutive numbers to be located at the same point in your video.

Dunno. If you’re strong on Excel and on PowerPoint animations, give it a ponder?